# document.write and loops

Tags: javascript, document.write

Context: I'm learning Javascript and many of the practice codes use document.write(), however I've been reading that it should be *avoided*, however some things in JS have embedded document.write()

e.g.

```
var i = 1; 
do {
    document.write ("Cool"); 
    i = i + 500;
} while (i <= 10);
```

Question: do you attempt to rewrite the loop with an alternative document.write() method (e.g. `createELement` or `innerHTML`), or do you simply do your best to avoid its use?

Comment: You can do it by concatenating to `innerHTML`: `element.innerHTML += "Cool";`

Comment: Or you can do this: https://jsfiddle.net/sod5wrxj/

Comment: just use console.log() if you are learning the basics

Comment: Your loop will run only once, so it can be replaced with `document.write("Cool");`.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to refactor the write() call to something else like appending to `innerText` or `innerHTML`, or (better) creating an element and appending it as a child.